# Pass username from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Controller

```
public function aksi_login(){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $username = $this->action->getNamaLogin();    

    $cek = $this->action->cek_login("anggota",$where)->num_rows();

    if($cek > 0){
        $data_session = array(
        'nama' => $username,
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
}
```

My Model

```
   function getNamaLogin($email)
   {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Nama FROM anggota WHERE Email = '$email'");
   }
```

My View

```
<h2>Welcome <?php echo $this->session->userdata("nama"); ?></h2>
```

I want to pass the username when user log in to session and show the username in view. but when I var_dump($username) the value is NULL and the username didn'y show in view. Do I make a mistake, or there are another good ways to do what I want?

Comment: You do no verification of the users password. This logic means anyone can access your system with a correct email. This is bad engineering anyway you cut it.

Comment: ofc I verify user password, It better to not copy all code cause it will be a mess

Comment: Ok that's good :) someone else I was helping on stack wasn't doing anything with it and they didn't even understand why it would be necessary as if php just knows what to do. But still, it would be nice to have all the relevant code otherwise it can be a guessing game.

Comment: For example it would useful to see how you handle the else of $cek > 0

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your $username is not empty. Then pass data from controller to view by loading view in controller method.

In Model function:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT Nama FROM anggota WHERE Email = '$email'");
return $query->result();
```

In Controller function:

```
$username = $this->action->getNamaLogin($email);   
$data['username'] = $username;
$this->load->view('view_page', $data);
```

In View_page.

```
<?php echo $username;?>
```

Find More https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: I don't know why my $username returning null, do I make a mistake in my model? but it success when I run my query in phpmyadmin

Comment: Your are not returning any thing from your model. Edited my answer.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: username

Filename: views/main.php

Comment: try to print $username in the controller. print_r($username); And you are not passing $email as a parameter.

Comment: You are doing `$data['username'] = $username;`?

Comment: And you passed email to the model because you weren't. If not repost your current code or put on pastebin along with all relevant functions - I'm not a fan of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

In `getNamaLogin()` do:

`return $query->row()->nama`

I would also suggest adding an else condition if the user doesn't exist or password is inccorect that will redirect the user back to the logic page with an error message. Currently there is no logic for this and the user will face just a blank page unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: same error, I think its about passing variabel from controller to view

Comment: print_r($query->result()); and tell me what it is. Do directly after $query

Comment: Yes, I add an alert in else

Comment: I also don't understand your logic. You submit the form to the same page where you load the view and you show view before redirect, doesn't make sense...

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Nama] => test ) ). do you mean 2 main page, I will change that later. I just code that temporary for fast result, If i view at the first one, then redirect its not work right?

Comment: Ah well use all of your original code (as seen in your question) and just change that one line! Should work fine!